# Python: Map class's function in the static scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I want to mark the reference to my class's function with in the static scope i.e I want something like:

```
class MyClass:

    func_mapping = {
        'key_1': func_1,  # Not accessible in this scope
        'key_2': func_2
    }

    def func_1(self):     # instance's functions
        # Do something

    def func_2(self):
       # Do other things
```

How can I map my functions like this?

My desired class structure based on the use-case is like:

```
class PlanTravel:
    travel_mapping = {
        'country_1': {
             'precondtion': ['condition_1', 'condition_2'],
             'planner': _travel_contry_1
            },
        'country_2': {
             'precondtion': ['condition_1', 'condition_2'],
             'planner': _travel_contry_2
            }
        }


    def __init__(self, conditions, country):
         self.conditions = conditions
         self.country = country

    def _verify_precondition(self):
        preconditions = PlanTravel.travel_mapping[self.country]['precondtion']
        for condition in preconditions:
            if condition not in self.conditions:
                raise Exception('You can not plan travel:', condition)

    def travel(self):
        self._verify_precondition()
        travel_func = PlanTravel.travel_mapping[self.country]['planner'] 
        travel_func()

    def _travel_contry_1(self):
        # Somthing

    def _travel_contry_2(self):
        # Somthing else
```

**Edit:** As mentioned by @vaultah, I can firstly define the functions and then map them to the `dict` as then they will be available within the scope. But I want it at the start of the class. In case someone wants to go through my code in future, then they can see the mapping at the very start and they know which function to refer.

Comment: You can do `func_mapping = {'key_1': func_1, 'key_2': func_2}` after you define `func_1` and `func_2`.

Comment: Any way to do it at the start. Before defining them?

Comment: I don't think you can refer to functions that aren't defined yet

Comment: I can't understand the reason for the mapping though, You will still have to reference it using `MyClass` so why bother? Also they have to be class functions.

Comment: You can't, although since a class is already a (fully introspectable) mapping between names and functions, it's not clear why you need this construct.

Comment: Added the use-case structure related to why I want this

Comment: It's not much clearer from the examples, if anything, it looks _more_ like you're reinventing classes and/or not leveraging the dynamic behaviour tools the language already gives you.

Comment: If you have to create the object then why are you making it a class attribute? There is really no need to unless you have `classmethods` that require it.

Comment: I added a [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40949069/2063361) based on feedback and answers in this post. Feel free to give suggestions/criticism on that.

Answer (score 1):

The only other way I can currently think of this getting passed the name resolutions is if you add it in a lambda and resort to an extra function call during lookup:

```
func_mapping = {
    'key_1': lambda: MyClass.func_1, 
    'key_2': lambda: MyClass.func_2,
}
```

Now, unfortunate access must be made with:

```
MyClass.func_mapping['key_1']()
```

Another option, wrap it in a function, names are only looked up during execution and not compilation:

```
def func_mapping(key):
    func_mapping = {
        'key_1': MyClass.func_1, 
        'key_2': MyClass.func_2,
    }
    return func_mapping[key]
```

this is a bit better on the eyes but you do get the extra function as a burden.

Comment: Added two different approaches I could think of.

Comment: I added a [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40949069/2063361) based on feedback and answers in this post. Feel free to give suggestions/criticism on that.

Answer (score 1):

The straight-forward way to achieve the behaviour that you want is to define `func_mapping` in the `__init__` method of the class. Sure, it gets redefined each time you create an instance, but so what? It's only a tiny dictionary.

Here's a demo that works on Python 2 and Python 3.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, mode):
        func_mapping = {
            'key_1': self.func_1,
            'key_2': self.func_2,
        }
        self.func = func_mapping[mode]

    def func_1(self):
        return 'one'

    def func_2(self):
       return 'two'

a = MyClass('key_1')
print(a.func())

b = MyClass('key_2')
print(b.func())
```

**output**

```
one
two
```

Comment: I added a [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40949069/2063361) based on feedback and answers in this post. Feel free to give suggestions/criticism on that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code almost works, you'll just need to define the methods *before* the mapping, and also not reference them via the class name as it is not defined yet:

```
In [2]: class MyClass:
   ...:     def func_1(self):
   ...:         pass
   ...:     def func_2(self):
   ...:         pass
   ...:     func_mapping = {
   ...:         'key_1': func_1,
   ...:         'key_2': func_2
   ...:     }
   ...:     

In [3]: 

In [3]: MyClass.func_mapping
Out[3]: 
{'key_1': <function __main__.MyClass.func_1>,
 'key_2': <function __main__.MyClass.func_2>}
```

Comment: This was already the part of my question. See Edit 1. But I do not want to do it. I added a [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40949069/2063361) based on feedback and answers in this post. Feel free to give suggestions/criticism on that.

Comment: You have very peculiar requirements... ;-) This answers the original question at least.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to store the method names as strings and then use `getattr`.

```
class PlanTravel:
    travel_mapping = {
        'us': {
             'precondtion': ['condition_1', 'condition_2']
             'planner': '_us_planner'
            }    
    # --cut--        
    def travel(self):
        self._verify_precondition()
        getattr(self,
                PlanTravel.travel_mapping[self.country]['planner'])()
```

Answer (score 0):

On giving a second thought on this, I think it is not possible to achieve it following the standards of coding. My approach to solve this is:

```
class PlanTravel:

    def __init__(self, conditions, country):
         self.conditions = conditions
         self.country = country

    def _verify_precondition(self):
        country_preconditions = { 
            'country_1': ['condition_1', 'condition_2'],
            'country_2': ['condition_2', 'condition_2']
        }

        preconditions = country_preconditions[self.country]
        for condition in preconditions:
            if condition not in self.conditions:
                raise Exception('You can not plan travel:', condition)

    def travel(self):
        self._verify_precondition()

        travel_func = { 
            'country_1': self._travel_contry_1,
            'country_2': self._travel_contry_2
        }
        travel_func[self.country]()

    def _travel_contry_1(self):
        # Somthing

    def _travel_contry_2(self):
        # Somthing else
```

Then I can call this as:

```
 plan_travel = PlanTravel('country_1')
 plan_travel.travel()
```

This class looks clean to me. But the negativity is, I will be doing the country mapping at two places. But on the second thought, these mapping are done at the block where these fields are required, which makes perfect sense to me.

*Feel free to criticize me on this. Any suggestion/criticism is most welcomed :)*

Comment: It still looks like you're reimplementing dynamic dispatch. All of this can simply go into a class called Country (or something else that fits your model better) which can be initialized with name and condition checks and potentially the travel method itself which seems country specific.